# Struts 2 Populate select drop list

Tags: struts2, tiles

Hi i want to populate the select drop down list with some value. I use Struts 2, Tiles and JSP. I initialize my list in the Action class but i am still getting the following error :
 **Caused by: tag 'select', field 'list', name 'anneeResultat': The requested list key 'anneesResultatsList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]**
Here is my code in Action class:

```
private AnneeResultat anneeResultat;
private Map<String, String> anneesResultatsList = new HashMap<String, String>();

public Map<String,String> getAnneesResultatsList() {
    this.anneesResultatsList.put("2005","2005");
    this.anneesResultatsList.put("2006","2006");
    this.anneesResultatsList.put("2007","2007");
    this.anneesResultatsList.put("2008","2008");
    this.anneesResultatsList.put("2009","2009");
    this.anneesResultatsList.put("2010","2010");
    this.anneesResultatsList.put("2011","2011");

        return this.anneesResultatsList;
    }
    public void setAnneesResultatsList(Map<String,String> anneesResultatsList) {
        this.anneesResultatsList = anneesResultatsList;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
    }
```

My struts.xml file contains :

```
<action name="ChoixAxes" class="fr.si2m.occ.web.actions.ChoixAxesAction"
            method="execute">
            <result type="tiles">choixAxes.tiles</result>
        </action>
```

My jsp is here:

```
<s:set name="theme" value="'xhtml'" scope="page" />
        <s:form action="ChoisirAxes" name="choices" id="choices">
         <s:select name="anneeResultat" label="Année de résultats" list="anneesResultatsList"></s:select>

        <s:radio label="Listes nominatives" name="listesNominatives" list="#{'1':'Oui','2':'Non'}" value="2" />
        <s:submit value="Calculer provisions" name="calculerProvisions"/>
        <s:reset value="Annuler" />
        <input type="button" value="Critères sauvegardés" id="criteresSauvegardes"/>
        </s:form>
```

Some one could help me please ?
I have this problem since yersterday.

Comment: have you declared `anneesResultatsList` inside your action's method? since OGNl will look it at action level and not inside the method

Comment: the "return success }" makes it difficult to understand whether it's at action level or inside method.

Answer (score 0):

> Prepare interceptor calls prepare() on actions which implement
>   Preparable. This interceptor is very useful for any situation where
>   you need to ensure some logic runs before the actual execute method
>   runs.

Your action should extend Preparable interceptor and override prepare() method, give the pre populated data.

[Struts2 Prepare Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/prepare-interceptor.html)

Comment: i believe OP has defined this property inside the method and OGNL is searching it in value stack as Action's property and not able to find it. you need not to do this inside preparable method

Comment: I implements the Preparable Interface and add prepare method in my action which initialize my list. But the problem remains. It's not data which are missing but Struts does not recognize my list objet !

Comment: @Umesh Yes, you are right but I'm trying suggest to do it in a better way.

Comment: To solve this problem Struts2 come up with beautiful feature just append ?debug=xml and find the anneesResultatsList is available in valuestack or not. refer the link http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/debugging.html

Comment: ?debug=xml does not show Action attributes ! It shows class, locale, action name,...

Answer (score 0):

Put AnneesResultatsList in session

```
Map session=ActionContext.getScession();session.put("list",AnneesResultatsList );  
<pre>
s:select name="anneeResultat" label="Année de résultats" list="%{#session.list}""></s:select>
</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

actually it is,

```
Map session = ActionContext.getcontext().getsession();
session.put("key",list);

<s:select list="%{#session.key}">
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief to make it more useful for OP and other readers.